# expressing trigonometric function in term of $\sin\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Hi could anyone help out with a final year high school problem?

**Q:**
Differentiate $\sin^{n-1}\theta\cos\theta$, then express the result in term of $\sin\theta$.

Comment: Use the product rule.

Comment: What's bothering you? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using product rule, you get, $$(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{n}\theta$$
(pretty straight forward so step is not shown)

You want all of them interms of $\sin\theta$, so just substitute $\cos^{2}(\theta)$ with $ 1-sin^{2}(\theta)$ to simply get,$$(n-1)\sin^{n-2}-n\sin^{n}(\theta)$$

Comment: yes this is a useful formula

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin^{n-1}\theta\cos\theta)$$
$$=\cos\theta\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin^{n-1}\theta)+\sin^{n-1}\theta\cdot \frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos\theta)$$
$$=\cos\theta\cdot (n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta \cdot \cos \theta+\sin^{n-1}\theta\cdot (-\sin\theta)$$
$$=\cos^2 \theta\cdot (n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta-\sin^n\theta$$
$$=\sin^{n-2}\theta \cdot [\cos^2 \theta\cdot (n-1)-\sin^2\theta]$$
$$=\sin^{n-2}\theta \cdot [n\cos^2 \theta-1]$$
$$=\sin^{n-2}\theta \cdot [n(1-\sin^2 \theta)-1]$$
$$=\sin^{n-2}\theta \cdot [n-n\sin^2 \theta-1]$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks...but I want everything in power of $\sin\theta$ only. I guess if you replace $\cos^2$ with $1-\sin^2$ will do the job

Comment: @math101 Yes you are right. Check my edit. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(\theta)=\sin^{n-1}\theta\cos\theta$$
$$F'(\theta)=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta(\cos\theta)\cos\theta+\sin^{n-1}\theta(-\sin\theta)=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta\cos^2\theta-\sin^{n}\theta$$

It is known that $\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$.

Thus,
$$F'(\theta)=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)-\sin^{n}\theta=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta-(n-1)\sin^{n}\theta-\sin^{n}\theta=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}\theta-n\sin^{n}\theta$$

Comment: yes this is what i mean.